# Is there a name for a sentence including both past and progressive verbs in different clauses (but not past progressive verbs)?

Tags: verbs, punctuation, conjugation

Say I have a sentence where the first clause is in simple past tense, but the following clauses are in present progressive:

"I hesitated, sipping at my tea to gather myself."
"She cradled the baby in her arms, cooing at its babbles, smiling at its smiles.'

Is there a name for that construction?  Do the progressive verbs count as past progressive because they've been placed in the past by the initial verb? Is it technically incorrect usage (though I don't particularly care about the technicality of it since it's widely used and understood)?

I'm pretty sure it doesn't trigger any special punctuation rules as these are quite common in fiction writing, and there doesn't seem to be anything unique done in response to them. I'm mostly just curious.

Comment: that sipping phrase is not a present progressive tense or a clause. That is a participle or participial phrase. This has two clauses:  "I hesitated as I was sipping at my tea to gather myself."

Comment: Most would analyse the ing-clauses as clauses nowadays. But they're untensed (the timeframe can often be deduced from context: here, synchronicity).

Comment: Does it mean that I hesitated to gather myself, or is it a purpose infinitive? Either way, it represents another clause. Oh, and no, there is no special name for such a sentence, nor for any sentence based on the tenses used in it.

Answer (score 0):

In those examples, "sipping," "cooing," and "smiling" are participles modifying the subject, not finite verbs in the present or past progressive.

Answer (score 0):

Two sentences with the same subject can be combined by reducing one of them to a participle clause (warning: grammar terms vary):

> *I hesitated. I sipped at my tea to gather myself.* →
>
> *I hesitated, sipping at my tea to gather myself.*

The participle clause has no tense; it follows along with the tense in the main clause.

You are correct that this technique is often employed for literary effect. Literary bonus: Your second example employs the rhetorical device called asyndeton, where an *and* is omitted and replaced with a comma:

> *She cradled the baby in her arms. She cooed at its babbles and smiled at its smiles.*  →
>
> *She cradled the baby in her arms, cooing at its babbles, smiling at its smiles.*

I don’t know if there’s formal name for the result of this reduction and combining, though.